# Trivial deserialization failing with YamlDotNet

Tags: yamldotnet

What can possible go wrong with this:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        var input = new StringReader(Document);

        var deserializer = new Deserializer(namingConvention: new CamelCaseNamingConvention());
        var p = deserializer.Deserialize<Person>(input);

        Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
    }

    private const string Document = @"Name: Peter";
```

A serialization exception is thrown:

```
Property 'Name' not found on type 'YamlDotNet.Samples.DeserializeObjectGraph+Person'
```

The same happens if I first serialize a Person object using the Serializer.

While the online sample for deserialization works just fine - this trivial code does not. What am I missing? It must be a stupid little detail. (But it happened before with other data structures I tried.)

Comment: Not that it's relevant to this question but perhaps good for other readers. 

The cause of my trivial failure was that i was using internal properties instead of public properties in the class used for deserialisation. Making them public fixed everything.

Answer (score 6):

As it seems, the problem is with the namingConvention parameter. If I don't set it to an instance of CamelCaseNamingConvention all is fine.

Unfortunately the "canonical" example (https://dotnetfiddle.net/HD2JXM) uses it and thus suggests it is important.

Comment: You can use `PascalCaseNamingConvention` if that is the name of your source classes

Answer (score 2):

For any reason the CamelCaseNamingConvention converts the fields to lowercase in the class (ie. 'Name' to 'name'). As the string is 'Name' and not 'name' the  deserialization fails. The example uses lower-case therefore it works....
I had the same problem....